# Changing 'NULL' value to '0' in label formula

Tags: qgis, labeling, null, formula

I have a label formula in QGIS that shows the name of a polygon and the remaining km of survey left to do:

```
"Name"  ||  '\n'  || round("Length_km_sum", 2)
```

But when I have an area that is complete (i.e. length_km value for the polygon shows as `NULL`) I would like for the label to show `0` or `'Complete'`.

Right now if the value is `NULL` the label doesn't even show on the map.

Comment: have you tried using the `coalesce` function?
try: `"Name" || '\ n' || coalesce (round ("Length_km_sum", 2), 0)`

Comment: @pigreco This seems to be a/the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases a good solution is to use the [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#coalesce) function like this:

```
"Name" || '\ n' || coalesce(round("Length_km_sum", 2), 0)
```

Comment: One error to fix and this solution worked perfectly, many thanks-

"Name" || '\n' || coalesce(round("Length_km_sum", 2), 0)